# How to turn old PCs into a personal cloud?

Tags: cloud

I have three old PCs and I want to turn them into a personal cloud. Basically, I want to make best use of these three CPU by combining their processing power. I was thinking to use [Eucalyptus](http://www.eucalyptus.com/). There are another options like [EyeOS](http://www.eyeos.org/) or Tonido too.

What is a general guideline that I should follow to make best use of these CPUs? Are there any other options that you would like to suggest?

Comment: FWIW, one small thing to keep in mind is your power costs of running multiple old machines continuously.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest cloud computing (as you are referring to it here) doesn't **sometimes** involve elasticity (as the person above me suggests) - it *necessarily* does.  If you want a front end, either in the form of a web interface or a command line interface, to be able to provision machines at will - you will have to dedicate resources to that front end.

If you don't - you might want to look at ScaleMP : http://scalemp.com/ . It allows you to aggregate x86 computing resources and then to treat them as one - in some ways.  It may be just what you are looking for.

Either way you go - I can see the usefulness of this as a learning exercise.  As an actual day to day tool to get work done I expect the price (to run this solution) to performance ratio will leave you disappointed.

Comment: Just look at one of the examples in the question, eyeOS. It touts itself as a Could Computing platform but has nothing to do with elasticity and only deals with managing data. As you state, "to be able to provision machines at will", i.e. virtualization, is a use for cloud computing, not the definition of it.